# Notification on updates

Tags: support, recent-activity, notifications

I would like to get an email if there is an activity on one of the questions I asked or on ones I subscribed to.

I would have assumed this is possible but I missed the function up to now.

Is this function available - and if so, how to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open your account settings by clicking in your profile details (upper mid screen)
- Edit Profile and Settings
- Preferences
- Check the 'Email me my unread inbox messages' box
- Set the frequency you want to receive mails

Hope this helps!